# php file_get_contents return 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, file-get-contents

With the following php code

```
$url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=EURUSD%3DX&a=6&b=27&c=2011&d=7&e=05&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv";
$this->trace("Geting from: $url");
$raw_quote_data = file_get_contents($url);
```

yahoo.com is returning a 404 Error, but the url is correct and works under my Internet browser.

I have try also set a header with the user agent with stream_context_create, but not works.

Maybe is a problem of my hosting (000webhost) and yahoo block it?

Comment: Works great on my server

Comment: When i remove `c=2011` it works just fine... Also works with 2010 and before (at least up to 2000). Perhaps the data is not available for that period, or the period is too short? But that doesnt explain why it works for Zerk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Curl function.It works fine for me.

```
<?php

$url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=EURUSD%3DX&a=6&b=27&c=2011&d=7&e=05&f=2011&g=d&ignore=.csv";
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
$response = curl_exec($process); 
curl_close($process); 

echo $response;
?>
```

Output i got:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close 2011-08-04,1.43,1.43,1.43,1.43,000,1.43 2011-08-03,1.43,1.43,1.43,1.43,000,1.43 2011-08-02,1.42,1.42,1.42,1.42,000,1.42 2011-08-01,1.44,1.44,1.44,1.44,000,1.44 2011-07-29,1.42,1.42,1.42,1.42,000,1.42 2011-07-28,1.43,1.43,1.43,1.43,000,1.43 2011-07-27,1.45,1.45,1.45,1.45,000,1.45
```